# Is it possible to disable and re-enable LaTeX editing?

Tags: front-end, latex

Entering text with the "^4" shortcut produces a selectable field which--when selected--allows one to edit the TeX.

After I am finished editing TeX, the mouse-over highlighting is annoying and accidentally selecting the TeX is also annoying.

[image]  -> [image]->[image]

Things would be less annoying if I could turn the TeX selection and editing off globally when I am done and re-enable it when I want to edit TeX again.

MaTeX is a great work around but, for one-offs that I frequently do, an on/off for the "^4"-mode would be nice to have.

***Is it possible to turn on/off TeX selection and editing?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $\TeX$-like expression is written as a `TemplateBox[..., "TeXAssistantTemplate"]`, and the front-end interactions with it are given by the `DisplayFunction` in the stylesheet. You can modify this to disable (or reenable) the editing function.

```
(* Save the default action *)
$defaultTeXDisplayFunction = 
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "TeXAssistantTemplate", 
   "TemplateBoxOptions", "DisplayFunction"}];

changeTeXDisplayFunction[func_] := 
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   StyleDefinitions -> 
    Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
      Cell[StyleData["TeXAssistantTemplate"], 
       TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction -> func}]}]];

turnTeXEditingOff[] := changeTeXDisplayFunction[#boxes &]
turnTeXEditingOn[] := changeTeXDisplayFunction[$defaultTeXDisplayFunction]
```

Then just use `turnTeXEditingOff[]` or `turnTeXEditingOn[]`. You can also put this to a toolbar or get them a keyboard shortcut.

[image]

---

Beware not to overwrite your `$defaultTeXDisplayFunction` when you have the $\TeX$ editing turned off. If you do so, this is the default:

```
$defaultTeXDisplayFunction
(* DynamicBox[InputAssistant`InputAssistantBoxes[1, "TeXAssistant", 
   Dynamic[#input], Dynamic[#boxes], Dynamic[#errors], 
   Dynamic[#state]], TrackedSymbols :> {#input, #boxes, #errors, #state, 
    InputAssistant`InputAssistantBoxes}] & *)
```

Comment: Wow! Super useful. Thanks!  Upvoting and accepting answer--and crossing my fingers that this might appear on the default toolbar.

Comment: ... might on the default toolbar as a radio button so that the current TeX-editing state can be saved with the notebook. e.g., a notebook level option.

Comment: Note: this has the effect of removing the Style definitions for any new styles that were created in the StyleSheet editor.

Comment: @CraigCarter, yes, sorry. I never use stylesheets, so I am always very clumsy with them ... I'll fix my code to preserve any changes!